# Erro no retorno do jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou utilizando php + jquery

o retorno é uma string do tipo

```
[["local","pressão instantânea"],["Campo Grande",1010.6],["Campo Grande",1011.1],["Campo Grande",1010.2]]
```

Sendo que no retorno vem uns metadados estranhos. Já li algo sobre CDATA.  Mas, não entendi como resolver essa questão. Alguém saberia dar um help?

```js
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: link,
    data: {
        idAtt: attributes,
        idData: idData
    }
}).done(function(data) {

    alert(data);
    console.log(data);
}
```

```js
<br />
<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-notice' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Notice: Undefined variable: cases in /var/www/html/dashboard_admin/models/eav-model.php on line <i>716</i></th></tr>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
<tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0000</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>236104</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='/var/www/html/dashboard_admin/index.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>.../index.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>2</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0000</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>236664</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>require_once( <font color='#00bb00'>'/var/www/html/dashboard_admin/config.php'</font> )</td><td title='/var/www/html/dashboard_admin/index.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>.../index.php<b>:</b>9</td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>3</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0001</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>237280</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>require_once( <font color='#00bb00'>'/var/www/html/dashboard_admin/loader.php'</font> )</td><td title='/var/www/html/dashboard_admin/config.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>.../config.php<b>:</b>40</td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>4</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0002</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>243544</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>EmergencyDashboard->__construct(  )</td><td title='/var/www/html/dashboard_admin/loader.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>.../loader.php<b>:</b>28</td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>5</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0003</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>250352</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>PresentationModelFacadeController->loadChart(  )</td><td title='/var/www/html/dashboard_admin/classes/class-EmergencyDashboard.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>.../class-EmergencyDashboard.php<b>:</b>131</td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>6</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0003</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>255240</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>EAVModel->getDataSelected(  )</td><td title='/var/www/html/dashboard_admin/controllers/presentationmodelfacade-controller.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>.../presentationmodelfacade-controller.php<b>:</b>71</td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>7</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0009</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>269072</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>EAVModel->getTransformations(  )</td><td title='/var/www/html/dashboard_admin/models/eav-model.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>.../eav-model.php<b>:</b>401</td></tr>
</table></font>
[["local","pressão instantânea"],["Campo Grande",1010.6],["Campo Grande",1011.1],["Campo Grande",1010.2]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acho que o problema é devido a um erro que dispara o debugador do framework que está usando. Com isso, o debugador desse framework printa a informação, que é uma espécie de backtrace do depurador, juntamente com o resultado json.

Isso que vc chama de "metadadados" deduzo que seja o backtrace do depurador do framework.

Corrija o erro apontado pelo depurador e provavelmente não terá mais o problema.

Segundo o debug, o erro é esse:

`Undefined variable: cases in /var/www/html/dashboard_admin/models/eav-model.php on line 716`

Uma variável undefinida, chamada "cases" no arquivo `/var/www/html/dashboard_admin/models/eav-model.php` na linha 716.